# PHP: Can I pass $this in the _constructor?

Tags: php, constructor, this

I would like to pass a php object in its own constructor to another object like this:

```
class foo {

 $parent_object;

 public function __construct($obj) {
  $this->parent_object = $obj;
  }
 }

class bar {

 public function __construct() {
  $blub = new foo($this);
  }
 }
```

The question I am asking myself is: Can I pass $this in the constructor of bar, because the object has not actually been created... so is $this already a valid reference to the whole object?

Comment: Running the code would have been faster than asking here :)

Answer (score 5):

Sure you can. Keep in mind that `$this` always points to the *current* object though. So in:

```
$blub = new foo($this);
```

`$this` points to the instance of `bar`. So `$obj` in the constructor of `foo` is that instance of `bar`.

`$this` is available at the beginning of the constructor. Now if `bar` immediately calls functions on `$obj` it might be that the instance of `bar` is not yet in the right state (ie. `$blub` has not been assigned). This could lead to reference issues, the solution to that would be to move the reference exchange out of the constructor.

Comment: If it was not possible, you could not set attribute values in the constructor, thus rendering it all pretty useless.

Comment: That's a sensible way of looking at it.

Comment: thank you for your answer! by stating that $this allways points to the current object: That means, should I somewhere later in the code do a $bar->property = 'value'; then $bar->blub->parent_object->property would also change, right?